# cron job won't open file_get_contents

Tags: php, cron, file-get-contents

i'm running a php script that uses file_get_contents in order to mail a list with what it's inside that remote file.
If i run the script manually everything works fine, but when i leave it and wait for the cron to run it doesn't get that remote content..... Is that possible?
i copy here a bit of the code where i think the problem is:

```
$flyer = file_get_contents('flyer.html');

$desti = $firstname." ".$lastname;

$mail = new phpmailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "orion.xxxx.com"; // line to be changed
$mail->Port = 465; // line to be changed
$mail->Username = 'bob@xxxx.com'; // line to be changed
$mail->Password = 'xxxx90'; // line to be changed
$mail->FromName = 'Bob'; // line to be changed
$mail->From = 'bob@xxxx.com';// line to be changed

$mail->AddAddress($email, $desti);

$mail->Subject = 'The Gift Store';    // to be changed



if ($cover_form == '1'){ $mail->MsgHTML($long10);} else
if ($cover_form == '2'){ $mail->MsgHTML($customer);} else
if ($cover_form == '3'){ $mail->MsgHTML($freedoers);} else
if ($cover_form == '4'){ $mail->MsgHTML($freelongform);}  else
if ($cover_form == '5'){ $mail->MsgHTML($freestoreshort);}  else
if ($cover_form == '6'){ $mail->MsgHTML($getasiteshort);}  else
if ($cover_form == '7'){ $mail->MsgHTML($flyer);}  
else {}
```

Comment: Where does `flyer.html` reside? If it is local, you should use an absolute path for cron.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cron doesn't load the code from the 'folder' you are in, so you will need to specify a full path

`$flyer = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "flyer.html");`

Comment: i'll try that, thanks both, flyer is local, so i'll change the path.

Comment: @Sebastian I like to put `chdir(dirname(__FILE__));` at the top of all scripts to  be run by cron to prevent this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The path of the file is different when the cron executes

Try

`$flyer = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/flyer.html');`

Or specify the path yourself

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
file_get_contents('flyer.html', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the output and errors get redirected to a file, so you can get an idea of what's going on with your script when run by cron.

The command in the crontab would look like this :

```
php /path/to/your/script.php >/tmp/log.txt 2>&1
```

Looking at your code, though, I would suggest you use an absolute path to open the `flyer.html` file, so your script works even if launched from another directory that the one containing that file.